# Como atribuir todas as características de um objeto para outro, menos uma em particular?

Tags: javascript, objetos, atributos

Eu estou Criando um card game que roda no navegador e preciso que em algumas situações, possam haver as mesmas cartas em mãos diferentes("Computador" ou Jogador). Porem, não quero ter que criar outro objeto para representar as cartas inimigas. Este logo abaixo por exemplo, e um objeto que representa uma carta.

```
Bherk_tropa = {
  nome: 'Bherk',
  raca: 'Anão',
  classe: 'Clerigo',
  id: 'Bherk',

  corpo_a_corpo: true,
  pesadas: true,
  longo_alcance: true,
  armadadura: true,

  pvInical: 150,
  pontos_de_vida: 150,
  ataque: 70,
  defesa: 80,
  agilidade: 06,
  brutalidade: 13,
  Efeito: function(){

  }
}
```

Para criar outra carta semelhante a essa na mão do inimigo mudando somente o atributo e id por exemplo, tentei a seguinte linha de código:

```
Bherk_tropa_Inimigo = Bherk_tropa;
Bherk_tropa_Inimigo.id = "BherInimigo";
```

Mas o resultado foi que quando alterado o id de Bherk_tropa_Inimigo o id de Bherk_tropa também foi alterado. Espero Conseguir esclarecimento através de alguma boa alma. Agradeço dês de já. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente com o [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Ele irá realizar de fato uma cópia do objeto, e não apontar para a mesma referência:

```
let Bherk_tropa_Inimigo = {...Bherk_tropa};
Bherk_tropa_Inimigo.id = "BherInimigo";
```

Outro jeito de fazer:

```
Object.assign({}, Bherk_tropa);
```

O funcionamento será o mesmo.

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigado amigo. Mas o que esse 'let' faz?

Comment: Ele inicializa a variável, no caso a `Bherk_tropa_Inimigo`, o mesmo que `var` porém possui um menor escopo. Caso utilize o código por gentileza aceite como a resposta correta. Obrigado.

Comment: Vlw, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

> Se não for um inconveniente, o *operador spread* não é suportado pelos
>   navegadores da Microsoft.

Você pode usar um `for...in` para inserir as chaves e seus valores de um objeto a outro:

```js
var Bherk_tropa = {
  nome: 'Bherk',
  raca: 'Anão',
  classe: 'Clerigo',
  id: 'Bherk',

  corpo_a_corpo: true,
  pesadas: true,
  longo_alcance: true,
  armadadura: true,

  pvInical: 150,
  pontos_de_vida: 150,
  ataque: 70,
  defesa: 80,
  agilidade: 06,
  brutalidade: 13,
  Efeito: function(){
  }
}

var Bherk_tropa_Inimigo = {}; // cria o novo objeto

for(key in Bherk_tropa){
    Bherk_tropa_Inimigo[key] = Bherk_tropa[key]; // copia as chaves
}

Bherk_tropa_Inimigo.id = "BherInimigo"; // altera a chave "id"

console.log(Bherk_tropa.id); // mostra o valor de "id" no objeto original
console.log(Bherk_tropa_Inimigo.id); // mostra o novo valor de "id" no novo objeto
console.log(Bherk_tropa_Inimigo); // mostra o novo objeto completo
```

Comment: muito obrigado!